Most correct way to navigate views with sidebar and also within detail views in swiftui?
I have a NavigationSplitView with a NavigationStack inside the detail section and a NavigationLink in the content section. This is for iPad.
I am managing navigation between views by appending a to variable path which is an @EnvironmentObject NavigationPath. I have been tracking the changes to see how it stacks and it seems to be correct.
When I reproduce with absolute basic setup and no work being done, it seems to navigate between views smoothly. When I run in my full app, it navigates well sometimes and crashes other times. I find if I am deliberately slow with navigating, it crashes much less (could be coincidence). The crash only occurs after navigating inside the detail and then pressing an item in the sidebar...I simply cannot figure out what is causing the crash. I get:
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range

But there doesn't seem to be a regular pattern to what is causing that. I have my view here with the root NavigationStack in the detail section. I found I was getting a Navigation error because I had NavigationStack inside a child view as well but that is sorted.
import SwiftUI


struct MenuView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(SidebarItem.allCases, id: \.self, selection: $app.selectedSidebarItem) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Label(item.rawValue, systemImage: item.iconName)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Menu")
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {
                if let selectedItem = app.selectedSidebarItem {
                    switch selectedItem {
                    case .planner:
                        InitialScreenView()
                    case .areaForecast:
                        AreaForecastView()
                    case .legal:
                        DisclaimerView()
                    case .customMinima:
                        CustomMinimaView()
                    }
                } else {
                    InitialScreenView()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: SidebarItem.self) { item in
                switch item {
                case .planner:
                    InitialScreenView()
                case .areaForecast:
                    AreaForecastView()
                case .legal:
                    DisclaimerView()
                case .customMinima:
                    CustomMinimaView()
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: DeeperLayerScreen.self) { item in
                switch item {
                case .resultsView:
                    ResultsScreenView()
                case .atis:
                    ATISScreenView()
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: app.path) { oldValue, newValue in
                print("changed from \(oldValue.count) to \(newValue.count)")
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(app)
    }
}

enum SidebarItem: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case planner = "Planner"
    case areaForecast = "Area Forecast"
    case legal = "Legal"
    case customMinima = "Custom Minima"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }

    var iconName: String {
        switch self {
        case .planner:
            return "house"
        case .areaForecast:
            return "cloud.sun"
        case .legal:
            return "doc.text"
        case .customMinima:
            return "doc.text"
        }
    }
}

enum DeeperLayerScreen: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case resultsView = "results view"
    case atis = "atis view"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

#Preview {
    MenuView()
}

From within the detail page I am then navigating only one or two pages deeper and then selecting an item in the sidebar which is then crashing.
This is my @ObservableObject class:
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var selectedSidebarItem: SidebarItem?
    @Published var selectedDeeperItem: DeeperLayerScreen?
}

And this is how I am managing navigation to a new view:
Either passing AppState to a view like this:
@EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
or to a class like this:
class LoadingClass: ObservableObject {

func LoadingProcess(app: AppState) async {

    }
}

And then appending like so:
        app.path.append(DeeperLayerScreen.resultsView)

I feel like there are so many ways to navigate and I am obviously doing something wrong there. Please help...

If you can switch to the new TabView it has a sidebar customization, they are in Beta now but overall solve this issue https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/enhancing-your-app-content-with-tab-navigation NavigationSplitView is not designed to work with navigationDestination the NavigationStack somehow "merges" with NavigationSplitView when you put it in the detail but it does not work as expected. You might be able to get away with something like NavigationStack(path: $app.path) {}.id(app.selectedSidebarItem)
